# Display equal width elements with grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-grid

I am trying to display fields in a row in the following form: Display 3 fields in a row with equal width, and the rest of them, if I have 2 fields to be in a row with equal width, and if there is one field left to be full width

[image]

I tried with this CSS:

```
root: {
        width: '100%',
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 1fr)',
        gridColumnGap: theme.spacing(),
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
```

But this is the result I got:

[image]

How can I achieve the expected result(first image) with CSS grid?

Comment: Use a 6 column grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two solutions for this. ***First*** instead of dividing the grid to 3 columns, divide to 6 columns and span the grid items into multiple columns by targeting them using `nth-child` selector. ***Second*** Don't use grid at-all, instead create a flex-container that will have another 3 flex-container as child nodes. And make use of `flex-basis` to get the desired result.

**Solution 1**
*Using a 6 column grid*,
You have to target specific grid items and make use of `span` to span them across `n` number of columns. For example for the first 3 grid item you need to specify `grid-column: span 2;`. Example,

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}


.grid-item:nth-child(1),
.grid-item:nth-child(2),
.grid-item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(4),
.grid-item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.grid-item:last-child {
  grid-column: span 6;
}
```

See the demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-http-cktlx?file=/src/styles.css:334-562).

**Solution 2**

Since you asked for a solution using CSS-grid, I don't think it is a good idea to include the code for the solution that uses flex-box instead. Have a look at the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-snow-ltezq?file=/src/styles.css:235-237), for the solution using flex-box.